# Drop down should not display all the dropdown values

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

The drop down I am using is statically bound.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="StartTime" runat="server" BackColor="#FFFF80" Font-Names="Arial"
                  Font-Size="Small" style="text-align: center" Width="56%">
  <asp:ListItem Value="12:00 AM"></asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem Value="12:30 AM"></asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem Value="1:00 AM"></asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem Value="1:30 AM"></asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem Value="2:00 AM"></asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem Value="2:30 AM"></asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem Value="3:00 AM"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Later I am retrieving the inserted value from DB and displaying it to the user from front end like:

```
ss.Append("FRE_PLANNED_START_DATE = '" & PlannedStartDate.Text & "',")
ss.Append("FRE_PLANNED_COMP_DATE = '" & CompDate.Text & "',")
```

Is it possible to show only the selected value and not the other drop down option to the user?

For example, while inserting the selected 12:00 AM and again front end should show only 12 and not display remaining drop down options.

Comment: Wouldn't you get the same effect by simply disabling the control?  Or not showing a control at all and just showing, say, a label with the value?

Answer (score 0):

You can hide one by setting its Enabled property to false:

```
StartTime.Items[0].Enabled = false;
```

You can loop it to disable all but one selected.
Wouldn't disabling DropDownList work as well?

Comment: If i disable the Drop down list then how can users select the initial value also. It is totally greyed out .

Comment: Disable dropdown after selection or at any time that you don't want to display remaining drop down options. Explain what you mean by "LATER"